# How to refer currently updating records in mongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is my collection

```
[{documentId: 123, id: uniqueValue }]
```

Expected result

```
[{documentId: 123, id: id1,uniqueKey: uniqueValue }]
```

How do I refer "id" column for currently updating records, also id column can be anything for which my outer query is giving me the column name

```
 db.supplier.updateMany( { documentId : 123}, { $set: { "uniqueKey": id} } );
```

so in above query "id" is coming like outerObject.mapping.idColumn which I want to substitute in above query.

---

***The whole point of doing this, is to create index on column, and current collection does not have fixed column name on which I want to fire a query***

**Example**

There are two collections ***collectionOne*** and ***collectionTwo***
for **each** document in collectionOne there are **multiple** document in collectionTwo. The **docId** is used for lookup.

---

```
collectionOne
[{
    docId :123,
    col1 : lookupColumn
    metaData: "some metaData",
    extra : "extra columns"
}, ... ]
```

---

```
 collectionTwo
    [{
       docId :123,
        lookupColumn:"1",
        a:"A",
        b:"B" ....
    },
    {   docId :123,
        lookupColumn:"2",
        a:"A",
        b:"B" ....
    }
    {   docId :123,
        lookupColumn:"3",
        a:"A",
        b:"B" ....},.....]
```

---

**lookupColumn** in collectionTwo may have different name and mapping of that name is given in collectionOne by col1 field (which is always same), in this example col1 value is ***lookupColumn*** so I want to create a column **newKey** and copy value of **lookupColumn** into it.

So I came up with  below Query

```
db.collectionOne.find({}).forEach(function(obj) {   
    if(obj.columns) {
        existingColumn =obj.columns.col1;
        db.collectionTwo.updateMany( { docId: obj.docId}, { $set: { "newKey": existingColumn} } );
        }
}
```

problem is I am not able to pick an existing column name using variable existingColumn, I have tried using $ as well, which inserts $"existingColumn" as newKey value.

I have updated query with one more loop over collectionTwo but I feel that in optimized  and unnecessary.

Comment: I'm confused by the question you're asking.  Can you give a specific example of the input and output you're expecting?

Comment: @LaurenSchaefer I will update the question.

Comment: I'm wondering if remodeling your data would be a better solution to your problem.  Instead of having two separate collections, you could embed the information from collection 2 in the appropriate doc in column 1.  In MongoDB, data that is accessed together should be stored together.  I think what you're describing is a one to many relationship:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: @LaurenSchaefer, I agree with your suggestions but this is the current design implemented and if you were to change design I will have to modify lot of my code + need to see backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

To go from

```
{documentId: 123, id: uniqueValue }
```

to

```
{documentId: 123, id: id1, uniqueKey: uniqueValue }
```

Use the pipeline style of update, which lets you use aggregation syntax:

```
db.collection.update({documentId: 123}, [{$set:{uniqueKey:"$id", id:"id1"}}])
```

**EDIT**

The latest edit to the question makes this a lot more clear.

You were almost there.

In MongoDB 4.2, the second argument to [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#update-many-update) accepts either an update document like you were using:

```
db.collectionTwo.updateMany( { docId: obj.docId}, { $set: { "newKey": existingColumn} } );
```

Or it can accept an aggregation-like pipeline, but not all stages are available. For this use, if you make that second argument an array so that it is recognized as a pipeline, you can use the "$variable" structure.  Since you already have the field name in a javascript variable, prepend "$" to the fieldname:

```
db.collectionTwo.updateMany( { docId: obj.docId}, [{ $set: { "newKey": "$" + existingColumn} }] );
```

Comment: will it also update value of id to id1, because I don't want to change id column and uniqueKey is just column name, it doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: I have updated the question, may be you will have more clarification.